# What are the irrational numbers that are generatable by a Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

Assume generating means that for all $k$ there exists $N_k$ such that after $N_k$ steps the $k$th cell on the tape consists of the $k$th digit of $\pi$'s binary expansion and will stay there forever.

Can such a machine exist? can it not?

EDIT

Is this true for every irrational number?

So this is true for $\pi$ since there exists a Turing machine to calculate the $k$th digit of $pi$ so we can construct a machine that calls the prior machine to calculate digit by digit.

But this can not be true for all irrational numbers since there are uncountably many irrational numbers and only countably many turing machines.

From this we can conclude that $\pi$ is among a special countable set of irrational numbers, call it $G$, that are generatable in the sense above.

> Do we know what is the set $G = \{ g \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} : g$ is generatable $\}$ in a mathematical sense or a more informative way? We know $\pi \in G$ and we know $G$ is countable. Is there more to the picture?

Comment: There is an algorithm to compute the digits of $\pi$. This algorithm can be implemented on a Turing machine.

Comment: Thanks let me expand the question please, Is this true for every irrational number?

Comment: It is a question of computability, whether there exists an algorithm to find the digits. There exist uncomputable numbers.

Comment: Thanks so one more thing, So it actually can not be true that it works for every irrational number since there are uncountably many irrational numbers. This means that $\pi$ is among some special countable set of irrational numbers such that they can be generated by a turing machine. What is the characteristic that makes $\pi$ generatable and other irrational numbers not?

Comment: It was already asked here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91847/how-to-prove-the-existence-of-a-number-which-cannot-be-written-by-any-algorithm/

Comment: The reals that you can somehow describe in words are also countable. And the ones that you can calculate with a Turing machine are a subset (since all these can be described in words by describing the Turing machine in words). So can you describe a number in words? If you can’t, you can’t calculate it. Obviously i can’t give you an example.

Comment: @Albert Hendriks: That is not the same question. Computable numbers are finite. These are the irrational numbers with enumerable (infinite) expansions.

Comment: @reinierpost That is not true, that question is not about finite numbers but about irrational numbers. Read further than the title.